# Why does Long equals return false when are the same value?

Tags: java, compare, equals

Running the following code I expect `true` as result, but the output I get is `false`.

```
Long value = new Long(0);
System.out.println(value.equals(0));
```

Why does the `equals` comparison of `Long` return `false`?

Comment: `0` is an `int` which is autoboxed to an Integer which is not equal to a Long as it is a different type.

Comment: try `value.equals(0L)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Long.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) return `true` only if the argument is also a `Long`.

The javadoc says:

> Compares this object to the specified object. The result is true if
>   and only if the argument is not null and is a **Long object that
>   contains the same long value as this object**.

In fact the following code gets `true` as output.

```
Long value = new Long(0);
System.out.println(value.equals(new Long(0)));
System.out.println(value.equals((long) 0));
System.out.println(value.equals(0L);
```

Answer (score 3):

looking inside in the implemented compare method you will find the critical criteria:

```
if (obj instanceof Long) 



public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

so passing any other numeric type will return false, even if the hold the same value...

```
Integer i = 0;
```

and

```
Long l = 0L;
```

are not the same in that context.

Answer (score 0):

You compared an Long with an int!
the .equals method also is checking the type of the Variable.
Here is a code to campare an int with an long:

```
int i = 0;
long l = 0L;

//v1
System.out.println(i == l);
//v2
Long li = new Long(i);
Long ll = new Long(l);
System.out.println(li.eqauls(ll));
//v3
System.out.println(((long)i) == l);
```